# Clustered file systems as XenServer storage

Tags: xen, storage-area-network, high-availability, cluster, xenserver

I want to use shared storage for a XenServer environment with 4 host servers which are running various VMs under XenServer. Planning to use 2 extra servers as storage with high availability of some sort.

While the most obvious solution is iSCSI SAN software, I see some recommendations that one skip iSCSI altogether and go for clustered file systems - most prominent seem GFS2 and Lustre.

However, I don't see options in XenServer which support connecting to such clustered systems.

First of all, do I need to then make the 4 XenServer hosts also part of the cluster? As I am installing via the Citrix download, I am not familiar how I would go about it, or if I even need to.

Don't need more than 30 VMs and storage is limited below 4 TB. Under these circumstances, what cluster type is best? Or does this not work at all with Xen?

Comment: When you say "shared storage", do you mean separate block devices divided off a central storage server and made available separately to each VM, or do you mean shared filesystems where the OS on each server sees a shared view of the same files?

Answer (score 0):

I never saw support for them from Citrix in official manuals. If I were you, I would go iSCSI. It's stable enough and good support.

Answer (score 0):

If you want XenServer to support this you will need to setup your cluster and then "reshare" a nfs or iscsi mount point for XenServer to use. Since it sounds like your 4 servers are tied up running XenServer I don't think a cluster makes a lot of sense for you